# Blazor Web App in .NET 8 and OnInitializedAsync

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

I am currently experimenting with the new Blazor Web App, having previously used Blazor WASM (and to a lesser extent Server). With my Blazor WASM app there was some code that I needed to run once the app had built and I was able to do this by utilising OnInitializedAsync in a custom component that I wrapped around Blazor's Router component. This would get called once the app had built and then I could move around the app and it wouldn't get called again.

With Blazor Web App I'm finding that if I try and do something similar, OnInitializedAsync is getting called every time I navigate between the sample pages/components (e.g. weather, component). Is anybody able to explain to me why that is as it doesn't appear to be the standard behaviour with WASM or Server?

Comment: Blazor WASM renders on the server by default and sends html to the client. The 3 Auto render modes have a constructor parameter of `prerender` set to true by default.

Comment: What do you mean `once the app had built`? Running something once per "session" or tab?

Comment: @BrianParker but apparently root components (i.e. the App component) can't be interactive so presumably don't prerender and yet if I add OnInitializedAsync to my app component and set a break point on that, it's getting called everytime I navigate between a page on the app?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos once per session

Comment: `App.razor` in 8 is static it only renders on the server.

Comment: @BrianParker so if that's the case, would you expect OnInitializedAsync to be called only the once for that component or called every time you switch between any of it's child components?

Comment: It is the case they discussed this in one of the release vids. Try put `@renderMode InteractiveAuto`  at the top you will see... All pages unless you tell them not to prerender as i said before render on the server first. So the html is built each time you navigate for the diff'ing engine.

Comment: Can you produce a [mre] to reproduce the problem, and then we'll all be on the same page.  With no code you could be doing things you don't think are important, but are.  You Can code a WASM app on 8 to work the same as a 7 app.

Answer (score 2):

It seems its about initial initialization of the application. To do that you must not use server-side rendering (which is the default in the Blazor App Template for some pages). You have to enable the InteractiveServer or InteractiveWebAssembly render mode on your router like so:

```html
@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

With that you can run your one time initialization in the App.razor file like so:

```cs
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Runs only once");
    }
}
```

The OnInitializedAsync will now only fire once you load / reload the entire page. It doesn't fire when you navigate across the pages because the router is now kept alive.

Pure server-side rendering is stateless, meaning you won't be able to easily persist state when navigating.