# How to figure out that is first loading of page or form submitting in .net 8 Blazor SSR

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0, form-post

I have a page that do both add and edit Commodities named CommodityAddEdit component. When we are in edit mode the Id is not null so we can figure out that we are in edit mode. In OnInitializedAsync() method I fill Model (vm) of EditForm. But after click on submit button the OnInitializedAsync() method executes too and vm fill again from database value record. How to figure out that we are filling form first time or we are in posting form mode in **OnInitializedAsync()** method?

```
<EditForm Model="@vm" OnSubmit="Submit" FormName="CommodityAddEdit"
          method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" Enhance>

[SupplyParameterFromForm]
private AddEditCommodityVm vm { get; set; } = new();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if (Id is not null) // update
    {
        var commodity = await appDbContext.Commodities.FindAsync(Id);
        if (vm.Title.Length == 0) // Load form data first time
            vm = commodity!.Adapt<AddEditCommodityVm>();
    }
}

public async Task Submit(EditContext editContext)
{
    if (Id == null)
        await Add(editContext);
    else
        await Update(editContext);
}
```

The **if condition is wrong** because maybe the user send empty fields.

Comment: OnInitializedAsync should be called only when the object is created on the first time. What is your Submit method is doing? Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: I added the Submit() method in question. I think Microsoft doesn't add a Property for figuring out the first load of OnInitializedAsync() is or not yet in Blazor SSR.

Comment: Check if this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77454995/1025320 resolves your issue.

Comment: Unrelated but advice from experience - don't create combined edit/add forms, no matter what tech you are using. It will save you a lot of troubles. If you want you can have AddEdit component that you add on two different forms (I tend to avoid that either but sometimes it might be worth it) but keep the forms separate.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did myself. I added a hidden input in EditForm and a bool property in vm named LoadForm with true default value and bind the hidden input to this property. Boolean default value is false and after creating the vm object the LoadForm become true and we can figure out that the vm is created and we are in loading mode of component and not in submit form mode.

```
<input type="hidden" @bind-value="vm.LoadForm" />

public class AddCommodityVm
{
    public bool LoadForm { get; set; } = true;

    [Required, Length(2, 50, ErrorMessage = Constants.LengthMsg)]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";

    public IFormFile? PdfFile { get; set; }
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Industries = await appDbContext.Industries.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    if (Id is not null && vm.LoadForm) // update : fill form
    {
        var commodity = await appDbContext.Commodities.FindAsync(Id);
        vm = commodity!.Adapt<AddCommodityVm>();
    }
}

<EditForm Model="@vm" OnSubmit="Submit" FormName="CommodityAddEdit"
          method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" Enhance>
    <input type="hidden" @bind-value="vm.LoadForm" />
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

            @* Title *@
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText @bind-Value="vm.Title" class="form-control" placeholder autofocus />
                <label>Title</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => vm.Title" class="text-danger" />
                @if (ShowAlert == true)
                {
                    <Alert Text="@AlertText" />
                }
            </div>

            @* PdfFile *@
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label>Pdf File</label>
                <label style="color:gray">@(vm.PdfName!=null ? $" (Now is : {vm.PdfName})": "")</label>
                <InputFile accept=".pdf" name="vm.PdfFile" class="form-control" placeholder />
                <ValidationMessage For="() => vm.PdfFile" class="text-danger" />
            </div>                    

            @* Submit button *@
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success w-50">
                    Submit
                </button>                    
            </div>

</EditForm>
```

---

Another solution without using hidden input. Just check HttpContext.Request.Method type for **GET** or **POST** string value. First inject **IHttpContextAccessor** to the **_Imports.razor** file then use it in c# file. When form post to the server the value is POST and when the page is opening the value is GET.

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if (Id is not null && HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.Request.Method == "GET")
    {
        var commodityPrice = await appDbContext.CommodityPrices.FindAsync(Id);
        vm = commodityPrice!.Adapt<AddEditCommodityPriceVm>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77430312/blazor-web-app-in-net-8-and-oninitializedasync/77454995#77454995) post, you need to put on the top of your component:

`@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveAuto`

With that, your OnInitializedAsync will enter only once.

Comment: I have also IFormFile in View Model, So @rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveAuto cause the file not upload in Submit(EditContext editContext) method and has null value. Also we don't want to use any RenderMode at all.